# como comparar una variable con expresiones regulares en php?

Tags: php

necesito comparar una variable usando php, les paso mi codigo para que me entiendad mejor

```
$palabra ="hola=Adv&%ASa";

if($palabra == "hola="){

    echo "bien"; 

}else{

    echo "mal";
}
```

lo que necesito es que me reconosca cualquier caracter que venga despues de la palta hola= y me lance el mensaje de bien,yo pienso que debe ser con expresiones regulares pero no se como aplicarlos en php. gracias

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php